# Prove relation between weighted average and mean of convex function

Tags: functions, proof-writing, convex-analysis

Take a continuous, convex function $f(x)$. Jensen's inequality states that:

$$ \sum_i f(x_i)\delta_i \geq f\left(\sum_i x_i\delta_i\right) $$

where $\delta_i$ are weights. Importantly, this function implies that the function evaluated at $\bar{x}$ is lower than the average of the functions, for a mean preserving spread of $x$. Graphically, for the case of two points, the point $D$ is necessarily higher than point $C$ (in vertical axis), if one assumes that $\frac{a+b}{2}=c$. The points $a$ and $b$ represent a mean preserving spread of $x$, and the point $D$ represents the average of $f(x)$ in that spread.

[image]

Define the absolute value of the spread as $\Delta=|a-c|=b-c$. Or equivalently, $a=c-\Delta$ and $b=c+\Delta$. It is evident from the graph that **the larger the spread is** ($\Delta$), **the larger is the difference between $D$ and $C$.** For $\Delta=0$, this difference is also zero.

Yet, I am struggling to prove this. From the graph, we know that

$$ \frac{f(c+\Delta) + f(c-\Delta)}{2} > f(c) $$

Multiplying each side by $\frac{2}{\Delta}$ and rearranging yields:

$$ \frac{f(c+\Delta) - f(c)}{\Delta} > \frac{f(c) - f(c-\Delta)}{\Delta} $$

This is clearly true, as the LHS represents the slope of the line joining points $B$ and $C$, whereas the RHS represents the slope of the line joining points $C$ and $A$. **It is evident that, the higher $B$ and the lower $A$ are (i.e. the higher $\Delta$ is), the wider is the difference between the two slopes.** But this is surely not enough for a complete proof. How can I mathematically proof this?

Comment: "The larger the spread is, the larger [...]" Is it? what about $\Delta = b-a$?

Comment: @ClementC. Assuming the function is defined along that spread, I don't see why it does not hold. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I may have misread your question, but won't D and C then coincide at B?

Comment: @ClementC. Recall the spread has to be mean preserving. Thus, the change is in both directions. Also, $\Delta$ is just a way to ease the maths. It is positive by definition, and the values of $x$ depart from the mean in both directions.

Comment: $\Delta=|a-c|=b-c$ implies $c = \frac{a+b}{2}$ and $\Delta = \frac{b-a}{2}$ .

Is that what mean ? If so the result clearly is obtained by definition of convexity. Just take $\lambda = \frac{1}{2}$ in definition of convex functions

Comment: But you may not have strict inequality $>$.  you have $\ge$

Comment: @Redshoes But, how do I prove that, the largest $\Delta$ is, the largest is the difference? Notice that I started the proof by using the covnexity definition. I don't see how to use it again.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the larger $\Delta$ implies the larger $h= |C-D|$,
That s not true in general.

For example look at the graph $e^{-x}$ on interval $[-3,20]$
.

Also  let $f:[0, 10] \to \Bbb R$ be convex function with $f(0)=f(10) =2$, which achieves its unique minimum at point $f(1)=0$, So then this $f$ works as  a counter example too .

Comment: I cannot see why it is not true in that interval. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: @luchonacho   if getting that is hard for you , try my other example. I edited my post

Comment: I think we are talking different stuff. The new example does not improve things. I suggest you plot the counterexample.

Comment: @luchonacho  So probably I didn't understand your question. maybe you need to be more clear by what  you want to show, formulate it mathematically  .

My examples just show, the difference $h$ is not maximized where $\Delta$ is largest possible i.e.,  $  \Delta = \frac{b-a}{2}$.

Comment: Fair enough. Will try to improve the question.